# text-size-adjust: none in DIV ( width 100%)

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a problem with text re-sizing on mobile devices. In DIV's with solid size the width is ok but In DIV's with 100% width the parameter text-size-adjust doesn't work. How can I turn the text re-sizing off?

I used this:

```
html {
    text-size-adjust: none !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none !important;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none !important;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(80,80,80);
    line-height: 19px;

.letter {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
```

Comment: post a fiddle of your issue along with HTML

Comment: http://www.rezervace.artworksmedia.cz/  live beta version, problem is in .news class for example